# How can Modernizr 3.x modules be required?

Tags: modernizr, browserify

I am trying to require specific Modernizr tests into a browserify project but i must be doing something wrong.

I use the [deamdify](https://github.com/jaredhanson/deamdify) transform when building using browserify.

Modernizr is required as an NPM package directly from the source repo's master. The reason this happens is because pending v3.x will be available through npm and the latest bower packages do not offer the sources, only prebuilt versions.

I want to be flexible with what Modernizr modules i include in my application so for my needs, having an extra build-modernizr step is not acceptable. I want to have a single build step, browserify.

The problem is that `deamdify` fails to recognize the required Moderizr modules as AMD and does not resolve their dependencies or wrap them in AMD containers...

I have setup a repo that illustrates the problem:

https://github.com/thanpolas/browserify-modernizr

Comment: It's sad why this question got downvoted. Slip it under the rag

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you aren't doing anything wrong. Its just not set up to work like that quite yet. Its a bit of a custom AMD.

[@robw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/530653/robw) has been [working on a new build system](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/pull/1184) that I believe would show you to do what you are looking for.

update: the new build system is finally in effect - using master as of 2/8/2015 you can require tests

Comment: I've checked out that PR multiple times (back when adding the .jshintrc file) ... i've seen this PR https://github.com/jaredhanson/deamdify/pull/9 on the deamdify repo and i want to see what @jaredhanson has to say...

Comment: when you say "custom AMD" does this mean that it simply won't be possible to require Modernizr files from source? Or it's just the 'baseurl` param that you use?

Comment: Actually the PR Rob’s working on won’t make this possible. Ultimately, individual detects aren’t the leaves in our dependency tree. Restructuring Modernizr so that they *are* could have performance implications. But let’s discuss it properly – https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1276

Answer (score 1):

Though you said that having an extra build-modernizr step is not acceptable for you (I provided [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44281813/746347) for that case) but still I want to add another answer for the case when using browserify and Modernizr with gulp.

[gulp-modernizr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-modernizr) can crawl through specified files, find Modernizr usages and make custom Modernizr build:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-modernizr
```

Define gulp task in `gulpfile.js`:

```
var modernizr = require('gulp-modernizr')

gulp.task('modernizr', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
        .pipe(modernizr())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

This task generates `build/modernizr.js` that contains only tests used in your source code. When added to html file with `<script>` tag this file sets `Modernizr` instance to `window.Modernizr` property. So you can use it like:

```
if (window.Modernizr.filereader) {
    // your code here
}
```

**Using modernizr as module.**

If you want to use modernizr as module (see [this issue](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1204) for discussion) than create `src/modernizr.js` file:

```
module.exports = window.Modernizr;
```

And expose this file as module with name `modernizr`:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('browserify', ['modernizr'], function() {
    var b = browserify({ entries: 'src/index.js' });
    b.require('src/modernizr.js', {expose: 'modernizr'});
    return b.bundle()
        .pipe(source('index.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

Now you can use it in your source code:

```
var modernizr = require('modernizr');

if (modernizr.filereader) {
   ...
}
```

**Injecting `build/modernizr.js` and `build/index.js` scripts in `index.html`.**

Suppose you have `src/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class='no-js' lang=''>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Example</title>
    <!-- inject:head:js -->
    <!-- endinject -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- inject:js -->
<!-- endinject -->
</body>
</html>
```

The following gulp task will inject `build/modernizr.js` in `head` section and `build/index.js` in `body` section and place resulting file to `build/index.html`:

```
var inject = require('gulp-inject');

gulp.task('html', ['browserify'], function() {
    return gulp.src('src/index.html')
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src('build/modernizr.js', { read: false }),
        { ignorePath: 'build', addRootSlash: true, starttag: '<!-- inject:head:{{ext}} -->'}))
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src('build/index.js', { read: false }),
        { ignorePath: 'build', addRootSlash: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With [browsernizr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browsernizr) you can specify what tests you need in your source code.

Install:

```
npm install --save browsernizr
```

Use:

```
// pick what tests you need 
require('browsernizr/test/css/rgba');
require('browsernizr/test/file/filesystem');
require('browsernizr/test/websockets');

// make sure to do this after importing the tests 
require('browsernizr');

// or if you need access to the modernizr instance: 
var Modernizr = require('browsernizr');
```

browserify will include required tests in bundle.